# How to update a TEXTVIEW(android studio) frequently when update occurs in MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql, switch-statement

[image]

Purpose Of my App:

1. If i toggle the switch button, a MySQL data(switch status- 0/1) will update.
2. If i change that data(switch status-0/1) from MySQL TEXTVIEW will update showing (ON/OFF).

First part is Done.

Need help to do 2nd part.

I have tried using Thread, but it results in blinking my App every 2 seconds,
which is very annoying.

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: you got something new to learn. search RxAndroid

Answer (score 0):

Ok so when the data is updates in **MySql** call another **function** which is responsible to getting the updated value from **database** and upon getting the value set it to text View. This will update your **TextView**.

Comment: "so when the data is updates in MySql"

how do my App understand that an update is occured in mysql?

Comment: You alreday told that your first part is done. Which said that your MySql data is update.
Then after make a function which gets that value and according to the value upade your UI